# Sort list of values in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Let's say I have the following dictionary:

```
diction = {"string": ["alabama", "fruit", "emoji"], "number": [9, 13, 20]}
```

How to obtain a dictionary where the values from "number" key are ordered descendingly and the "string" should be ordered as well as per the number key ordered? String and number key are linked

I want to get

```
diction = {"string": ["emoji", "fruit", "alabama"], "number": [20, 13, 9]}
```

I appreciate a lot.

Comment: How did `sorted` not work? Please provide the code you attempted to resolve your issue

Comment: Why not have a list of dicts like  [{"string":"Alabama","number":9}, ... ] having two lists who's sequence depend on each other sounds a like like they should be a key/value pairs themselves

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use sorted by another list selected by `diction['number']`:

```
diction["string"] = [x for _,x in sorted(zip(diction['number'], 
                                             diction['string']),
                                         key=lambda pair: pair[0], 
                                         reverse=True)]
diction["number"] = sorted(diction["number"], reverse=True)
print (diction)

{'string': ['emoji', 'fruit', 'alabama'], 'number': [20, 13, 9]}
```

Or use `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

d = pd.DataFrame(diction).sort_values('number', ascending=False).to_dict(orient='list')
print (d)
{'string': ['emoji', 'fruit', 'alabama'], 'number': [20, 13, 9]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method to obtain your desired output.

```py
from collections import defaultdict

diction = {"string": ["alabama", "fruit", "emoji"], "number": [9, 13, 20]}

d = defaultdict(list)
for strng, num in zip(diction["string"], diction["number"]):
    d[strng].append(num)

d = dict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True))

diction = {"string": [k for k in d.keys()], "number": [j[0] for j in d.values()]}

print(diction)
```

Outputs:

```
{'string': ['emoji', 'fruit', 'alabama'], 'number': [20, 13, 9]}
```

---

I am in agreement with [JeffUK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2207924/jeffuk)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70756620/sort-list-of-values-in-a-dictionary/70756713#comment125086550_70756620) about using key/value pairs. You can do this with the above snippet, but removing the line before printing which reconstructs `diction`

Answer (score 0):

`sorted` will work fine.

```
diction["number"] = sorted(diction["number"])
```

Comment: This sorts only the number key, not the whole dictionary

Comment: That is literally what your question asks for.

Comment: Please check again the expected output and look again at the "string" key

Comment: You will probably need to edit your question to make it clear what you're actually asking for. You asked to sort the `numbers` key. This will do just that.

Comment: I think they want to sort the 'numbers' list, but also sort the 'strings' list in the same way (i.e. assume they are linked, and sort both by the current position of the elements in 'numbers')

Comment: Exactly, JeffUK

Answer (score 0):

For a generalized approach that will sort all lists in the dictionary based on the reordering of sorting one of them, you can build a list of indexes in the new sort order and apply it to all the lists:

```
diction = {"string": ["alabama", "fruit", "emoji"], "number": [9, 13, 20]}

keys  = diction["number"]                      # list to sort
order = sorted(range(len(keys)),key=lambda i:keys[i],reverse=True) # indexes
for lst in diction.values():
    lst[:] = [lst[i] for i in order]           # apply new order to all lists

print(diction)
{'string': ['emoji', 'fruit', 'alabama'], 'number': [20, 13, 9]}
```